# Swift 4: Getting Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, swift4

Learning Swift 4 and AVFoundation and coming across an error when the 'Take Photo' button has been tapped, throwing a `'Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x596bbeb8)'` instead of navigating me to the preview view controller to show the image that was just captured.

(Happy to provide more code, just tried to pull out what i think might be relevant to keep question as short as possible :D)

**In my ViewController.swift:**

When the 'Take Picture' button is tapped, it called the takepicture() func.

```
func takePicture() {
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    cameraCaptureOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self) 
}
```

Then for the delegate:

```
extension ViewController : AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

        if let unwrappedError = error {
            print(unwrappedError.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            let imageCaptured = photo.cgImageRepresentation()!.takeRetainedValue()
            let finalImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageCaptured)
            displayCapturedPhoto(capturedPhoto: finalImage)
        }
    } 
}
```

The `displayCapturedPhoto()` func:

```
func displayCapturedPhoto(capturedPhoto : UIImage) {
    let imagePreviewViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imagePreviewViewController") as! imagePreviewViewController
    imagePreviewViewController.capturedImage = capturedPhoto
    navigationController?.pushViewController(imagePreviewViewController, animated: true)
}
```

**In my imagePreviewViewController.swift:**

```
var capturedImage : UIImage?

@IBOutlet weak var capturedImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    capturedImageView.image = capturedImage

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

The error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x596bbeb8)` occurs on the `capturedImageView.image = capturedImage`

Can anyone point me in the right direction of where i may have gone wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you paste the full error?

Comment: Are you sure you’ve setup the capturedImageView correctly?

Answer (score 1):

`AVCapturePhoto.cgImageRepresentation()` returns an Unmanaged CGImage Reference. If you `takeRetainedValue()` on it you consume an unbalanced retain, which may cause it early release and subsequent EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Try `takeUnretainedValue()` instead.

Comment: I can confirm this is true though not very intuitive. With `cgImageRepresentation().takeRetainedValue()` I had a seemingly unrelated crash later in the app, while `takeUnretainedValue()` (and using it immediately) helped.